# Why is my Rails migration "successfully" updating but not actually changing records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

Well this is a first.  I'm trying to run a migration for my Rails app (v4.2.0), and while the migration is succeeding, it's not actually changing anything.  Specifically, I'm trying to implement a `counter_cache` field for a table, assigning the start value for records that already have associations.

Here's my migration:

```
class AddCommentsCountToQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # dump SQL to console so I can see what's going on
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

    add_column :questions, :comments_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0

    Question.reset_column_information
    Question.find_each do |question|
      puts "updating record #{question.id} to have #{question.comments.count} comments"

      # use update! instead of update so that migration performs rollback on failure
      question.update!(comments_count: question.comments.count)

      puts "record #{question.id} actually persisted with #{question.reload.comments_count} comments"
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :questions, :comments_count
  end
end
```

My console output demonstrates that upon reloading the record, it didn't persist the `comments_count` value:

```
updating record 1 to have 8 comments
record 1 actually persisted with 0 comments
updating record 2 to have 0 comments
record 2 actually persisted with 0 comments
updating record 3 to have 0 comments
```

And lastly, you can see that the SQL UPDATE command is not doing anything other than changing the `updated_at` column on the first record (with 8 comments), despite passing a `comments_count` value in my attributes hash:

```
D, [2015-02-13T09:15:54.997805 #68245] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "questions" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "questions"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2015-02-13 16:15:54.992779"], ["id", 1]]
```

I'm making sure to call `reset_column_information` prior to updating any records, but it seems to have no effect.  I've done this plenty of times in recent past (the past few days even) and am banging my head against the wall here.

Comment: Have you tried updating previous records through the rails console rather than through a migration?

Comment: Just tried at your request, and the same happens there as well.  I've also verified that Rails is recognizing the column in general via `Question.inspect`, and it shows the column there: `Question(id: integer, user_id: integer, title: string, detail: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, votes_count: integer, votes_tally: integer, views_count: integer, comments_count: integer)`

Comment: I'm not sure why your version fails - it looks fine. Still, you might want to try the canonical version of populating counters: `Question.reset_counters(question.id, :comments)` in place of of `update!`.

Comment: Perhaps a validation is failing?

Comment: @SunilD. it does run an update query according to the logs, and the `update!` bang method would raise an exception otherwise.

Comment: @SunilD. What janfoeh said is true, and I already validated in the loop that the record is in fact valid, so that's a dead end.

Comment: @janfoeh Using `reset_counters` appears to work.  I wonder if there's some new logic behind counter caches that prevent that from being manually updated or something.  I'll do some digging, but if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MattHuggins not to my knowledge - in and by itself, it should be an attribute such as any other. I'm pretty sure I used to update counters manually your way not too long ago. It's puzzling. Is there anything fancy going on in your `Question` model? Callback magic, a stray `comments_count` setter method, something?

Comment: Nope, it's a pretty simple model!  Just a few validations on other fields, some relationships, and various methods.  No callbacks or anything like that attempting to alter values on attributes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your version fails - it looks fine. Still, you might want to try the [canonical version of populating counters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_counters):

```
Question.reset_counters(question.id, :comments)
```

in place of of `update!`

Comment: This did the trick!  I'm thinking it must have been a change to Rails core at some point, because I've definitely initialized counters in the manner outlined in my question in the past.  Perhaps there is something that's preventing columns that are managed by ActiveRecord from being manually updated, or something like that.